# Angularjs adjust width based on parent element width

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS & Bootstrap, and have the following structure:

```
<parent-div>
  <flexible-width-component 
            class="pull-left" 
            style="display: inline-block; min-width: 700px;">Data grid with many columns
  </flexible-width-component>
  <fixed-width-component 
            class="pull-right" 
            style="width:400px; display: inline-block">
  </fixed-width-component>
</parent-div>
```

I wish to have my `flexible-width-component` stretch to automatically fill the gap between itself and the `fixed-width-component`, for any resolution wider than `1200px`. 
Both components need to be displayed adjacent to each other.

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tried min-width, max-width & media queries, didn't help.

Comment: If I didn't have the fixed-width component, I would have used percentages for the div widths or bootstrap's scaffolding classes.

Comment: Is [flexbox](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/) and option?

Comment: @hitautodestruct its still not standardized so I'm not comfortable using it, and would prefer other options before going with flexbox

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get your parent containers `offsetWidth` and subtract your fixed width from it:

```
var example = angular.module('exmp', []);

example.directive('flexibleWidth', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {

      // Get parent elmenets width and subtract fixed width
      element.css({ 
        width: element.parent()[0].offsetWidth - 400 + 'px' 
      });

    };
});
```

**Here's <kbd>[a demo](http://jsbin.com/oHOdeMox/1)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

i know its very late to answer this question, but it might help others.

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ajk18n3/)

```
<div class="parent border">
  <div class="fixed-component border">
    Fixed Component
  </div>
  <div class="flexible-component border">
    flexible component
  </div>
</div>


<style>
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.flexible-component {
  flex: 1;
}

.fixed-component {
  width: 100px;
}
.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```